# How to use lag variable when you have missing year in database

Tags: mysql, sql, lag

I want to create new lagged variable from a database. I have use lag function in SQL. However, I have some missing year in my data. For instance, I have data in 2011, 2013, 2014, 2015. Normally the lagged variable in 2013 should be null but the lagged function in SQL take the value from 2011 instead of Null. Does anyone know how to fix this

Comment: You need to use a calendar table which contains all years which you expect to appear in your report.  The problem is not `LAG`.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen thank you for your reply. I have a column which contain Year. Do you know how to create a lagged variable from it

Comment: You already have the answer in the comment above - research "SQL Calendar Table".